# TASK allocation to empoyee

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe. The df1 has 12000 entries of different tasks w.r.t ' 3 tower' with 5 different dates. The df2 has 100 entries of associate names w.r.t that '3 tower''.  I have to allocate 100 associate names for the task 12000 task, upto limit 11 task per associate.  Please suggest.

I have tried PD.merge but it would not work with condition.

Comment: Please provide more details - your question is not clear. Provide the df1 and df2 and the required output. Provide the code for what you have tried and what issue you are facing with that as well.